# RegAsm : error RA0000 failed to load dll because it is not a valid .NET Assembly

Tags: regasm, installshield-2012

I am facing a problem with installshield 2012 while registering the DLL using Regasm from exec task in MSBuild script. Its giving the below error:

[Step 6/10] RegAsm : error RA0000 : Failed to load 'E:\BuildAgent\work\2ae7096f1a3f5702\dev\bin\Obfusc-Contributor\orgname.ShellExtension.FileManager.dll' because it is not a valid .NET assembly
[05:45:33]  [Step 6/10] RegAsm.exe failed.  E:\BuildAgent\work\2ae7096f1a3f5702\dev\bin\Obfusc-Contributor\orgname.ShellExtension.FileManager.reg was not created for Component Colligo.ShellExtension.FileManager.dll1
[05:45:33]  [Step 6/10] ISDEV : error -6210: An error occurred building COM .NET Interop information for Component orgname.ShellExtension.FileManager.dll1

This is happening on windows 10 . The same task is working fine on Windows 2008 machine